How correctly memset array of bool
I have bool array and I want initialize all elements to false. What is the correct way using memset. I see these examples on stackoverflow:
bool arr[10];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));

and
bool arr[10];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(bool) * 10);

What is difference and which way is correct, or are both of them fine?

They're equivalent. The size of an array is N times the size of the elements.

C++ even accepts bool arr[10]{}; although I'd recommend std::array<bool, 10> arr{};

Both are technically correct for your example, but you really shouldn't use either of them in C++.
To initialize the array to all false values, you can just include an initializer:
bool arr[10] = {};

To reset the array after it has been initialized, use std::fill() or std::fill_n() instead of memset(), and let the compiler optimize it.  For an array of primitive type, it will produce optimized code that is similar/equal to memset(), but will work out the necessary input for you.
bool arr[10];
...
std::fill(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), false);
// or:
std::fill_n(std::begin(arr), std::size(arr), false);


A for loop would probably generate the same code too :)

Even safer: std::ranges::fill(arr, false); but since your array is uninitialized, std::uninitialized_fill and std::ranges::uninitialized_fill sit better. fill is supposed to operate on initialized objects.

Both are correct, but the first is cleaner.
bool arr[10];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));

This sets arr to all bits zero. The standard guarantees that for any integer type, all bits zero is a representation of 0. I'd write sizeof arr rather than sizeof(arr) (sizeof is an operator, not a function), but either is valid.
bool arr[10];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(bool) * 10);

This is also valid, since the size of an array is by definition its length multiplied by the size of its element type. But you repeat the value 10, which makes the code vulnerable to errors if you later change the size of the array. (Here the parentheses on sizeof are required, since the operand is a type name rather than an expression.)
But an even better approach is:
bool arr[10] = { 0 };

This doesn't require a library call, and it initializes all elements of the array to 0 (false); the first is set explicitly, and the remaining elements are implicitly set to zero. Note that this applies only when initializing the array; if you want to reset its values later, memset is a reasonable method.
Another point: in current C, bool is not a predefined type. C has had _Bool since 1999, with a macro bool defined in <stdbool.h>; did you include that header? The 2023 standard, not yet released, will make bool a keyword and a predefined type name, but it's not supported yet. Or did you or some library you're using define its own bool type? It probably doesn't matter, since any reasonable boolean type will represent false as all-bits-zero, but it's still a good idea to show a small, complete, self-contained program so we can be sure what's going on.
